# How do I handle two project variations with two Mercurial repositories?

Tags: mercurial, repository

We have an application, which is open-source and published as GPLv2. We also have a slightly different version, with a commercial license. The differences between the two variations are very limited.

We have a main Mercurial repo for the GPL application.

I want to be able to keep a separate repo for the commercial application (the main one is public), but I also want to be able to regularly "push" changes to it (but not the other way round). Consider that these repos are hosted on a project hosting web service.

What I have done so far:

1. created a new *comm* repo
2. committed a first version of the commercial app (no history)
3. pushed *comm* to remote hosting
4. Modified *open-source* repo
5. tried to push from *open-source* to remote *comm*, hg says the repos are unrelated
6. tried to push from *open-source'*to *comm* with -f (force) option, hg now just shows a warning

The problem with step 6 is that I would push ALL changesets to the *comm* repo, which is not correct. I basically want to push changes since a given point in time (very much like merging two SVN branches).

I'm learning about the `hg transplant` extension, but that seems to be a bit complex to use on a regular basis.

I am new to Mercurial, so I might be doing it wrong, so please also suggest other ways of solving the same problem.

Comment: I think the main problem here is that you started with unrelated repositories. You should've created the commercial one as a clone of the open source one, and then pushed all your changes to it.

Comment: Well I can start over, no problem. Do you mean that I can clone starting from a specific revision (like the last one)?

Answer (score 1):

With a distributed version control system like mercurial you would clone the source repository in step 1 having two repositories with the same content at the starting point, namely *open-source* and *comm* as you called them. You would do your initial changes in your *comm* repository. As development proceeds in the *open-source* repo you would regularly pull changes into the *comm* repository and merge these with the changes there. This will produce additional merge changesets in the *comm* repo. As long as you don't push them back to the *open-source* repo you won't see them there and they should not disturb there, but that's what I understood you wanted anyway.